# pasar de jquery a Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo convertir este código de jquery a javascript puro, ya que quiero bloquear unos días en un calendario y este es el único código que he encontrado.

```
 <input type="text" value="Select Date Here"/>


var disabledDates = ["2015-11-28","2015-11-14","2015-11-21"]


<script>    $('input').datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: El problema es que tu código usa [`datepicker`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), que es parte de jQuery. Para pasar tu código en JS puro, tendrás que buscar una librería escrita en JS puro que sustituya a `datepicker`.

Comment: la verdad estoy usando esta libreria https://mauroreisvieira.github.io/hello-week/#/ que ya tiene un DisableDates, pero al traer la DB de las fechas que quiero bloquear no me funciona, lo estoy haciendo por medio de ajax

Answer (score 2):

Una opción podría ser usando [Pickaday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday) (no jquery), en el que la idea sería poder comparar las dos fechas. La misma idea se aplicaría a cualquier calendario.

```js
var disabledDates = ["2019-09-30", "2019-08-24", "2019-08-25", "2019-08-26"]

//quitamos los ceros a la izquieda para poder comparar 
disabledDates = disabledDates.map(e => e.split("-").map(n => +n).join("-"));


var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  position: "bottom",
  disableDayFn: function(date) {

    //El dia del calendario lo ponemos en un formato comparable
    let d = new Date(date);
    let dia = `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getDate()}`;

    if (disabledDates.includes(dia)) {
      return true;
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
margin:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/css/pikaday.css"> 
<div class="wrapper">
  Fecha
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, es decir que me puede funcionar con este calendario? https://github.com/mauroreisvieira/hello-week realmente es el que estoy usando, pero al traer de una DB el array no me funciona el DisableDates

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="date" min="2019-06-02" max="2019-06-08"/>
```

si mal no entiendo quieres bloquear ciertas fechas con un control `input date`, con el ejemplo de arriba funcioaria basicamente no cumpliendo lo que pides,

si es un `input text` debieras agregar el evento `onblur` y validar la entrada en dicho evento obviando las fechas que quieres sacar!

```
<input type="text" onBlur="ValidarFecha(this.value)"/>


function ValidarFecha(valor)
{
    if(disabledDates.indexOf(valor)=="")
    {
        //no existe fecha y pasa
    }
    else
    {
        //existe fecha hacemos algo
    }
}
```

Comment: espero funcione con lo que actualice!